# Error near Where in SQL command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to update two columns from two tables. I get an error near 'Where'. But, I don't see any error in doing the same. Any help ? Thanks :)

```
UPDATE MP 
SET MI.Accountid = AD.Accountid
FROM [GSF].[dbo].[MetaInformation] MI
inner join [GSF].[dbo].[AllocationDetails] AD
WHERE MI.AccountDetailID = AD.AccountDetailID
```

Comment: Is MP a table or an allias?

Comment: Missing ON for the Inner Join.

Comment: and `UPDATE MP` should probably be `UPDATE MI`

Comment: my bad, its MI typo while copying .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ON` to specify the `JOIN` condition:

```
UPDATE MI 
SET Accountid = AD.Accountid
FROM
    [GSF].[dbo].[MetaInformation] MI
        inner join
    [GSF].[dbo].[AllocationDetails] AD
        ON
            MI.AccountDetailID = AD.AccountDetailID
```

You also can't specify a rowset alias on the left hand side of assignment in the `SET` clause.